# C# generic class contains list of <T> but I cannot access methods of the <T> class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic class,`DisplayGrid` ...

```
class DisplayGrid<T> where T : class
```

... which has a `List` of `<T>` as a property.

```
public List<T> allRows;
```

... within a property of `DisplayGrid` I want to iterate over `allRows` and access a method of `<T>` ...

```
foreach (T r in this.allRows)
{
  if (!(r.isAValidRow))
  {
    blnRowsValid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

... however attempting to make use of the `isAValidRow` method defined on `<T>` generates a compiler error ...

```
error CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'isAValidRow' and no extension method 'isAValidRow' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found
```

Reading back through old questions it seems this area has changed over the years. It seems unlikely that such a basic requirement would still be impossible ?

---

**EDIT 1** : In the original version of this question I perhaps went too far in trying to simplify the sample code. I only included a single `Row` class but what I meant to imply is that there were multiple classes which might be used as a 'Row' when instantiating the `DisplayGrid` class.

I have now adapted the classes below so that there are two different classes which might be used as the `<T>` of the `DisplayGrid` class.

In doing this I hope to address a number of comments which, correctly, suggested there wasn't any need to use Generics, or that the 'where' directive could be limited to the only class, `Row`, which I had supplied in the example.

In the changes to the example I have defined classes `RowA` and `RowB` and I do appreciate that as shown they are functionally identical but this is just to make a simple example - in actual use `RowA` and `RowB` would be sufficiently distinctive to justify their not being the same class.

---

## Full Classes

All <strike>Both</strike> classes referenced above appear below :

```
class DisplayGrid<T> where T : class  
{
    public List<T> allRows;

    public DisplayGrid()
    {
        this.allRows = new List<T>();
    }

    public bool hasRowMsgs 
    {
        get
        {
            bool blnRowsValid = true;
            foreach (T r in this.allRows)
            {
                if (!(r.isAValidRow))
                {
                    blnRowsValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return blnRowsValid;
        }
    }
    public bool isAValidTable
    {
        get {
            if (this.hasRowMsgs == false)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
class RowA
{
    public List<string> rowMsgs;

    public RowA()
    {
        rowMsgs = new List<string>();
    }

    public bool isAValidRow
    {
        get {
            return (this.rowMsgs.Count == 0) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
class RowB
{
    public List<string> rowMsgs;

    public RowB()
    {
        rowMsgs = new List<string>();
    }

    public bool isAValidRow
    {
        get {
            return (this.rowMsgs.Count == 0) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if I created a `DisplayGrid<string>`? That doesn't have an `isAValidRow` property. (This area *hasn't* changed over the years, btw. Not significantly.) Is there any reason your class is generic at all? If it only works with the `Row` class, just make it non-generic. As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions too.

Comment: ```where T : class``` ??  ```where T : Row``` seems more suitable

Comment: You can fix it by following @OlivierDepriester comment, but anyway I think something really wrong is going on there, are you sure this is what you need and / or what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In the light of the comments I realise my initial example could have been improved on in order to make clearer what I asking. I have now done that as an update to the question so if anyone has any other comments I would be grateful to hear from them.

Comment: Create an `IRow { bool isAValidRow { get; } }` interface, implement it in both `RowA` and `RowB` and change the definition of `DisplayGrid` to `class DisplayGrid<T> where T : IRow`.

Comment: @Lee : Thanks for your comment. I have done as you suggested and that was exactly what was needed, thanks ! I'm about to amend the question so that in the future other people can see a working version. Would you like to change your comment into answer so that I can mark it as correct ? Thanks again.

Comment: @glaucon - Please don't post working versions of your code in the question. Please post your own answer if this code answers the question. I have rolled back your update. Please look at the revision history to get the source text of your change which you can then post as an answer.

Comment: @Lee as per the edit from Enigmativity the working code is no longer in the question but instead I have written an answer of my own but if you would like to summarise your original comment as an answer I would be happy to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having read, and understood the significance of, the comment by Lee I now have a working version. The key to making it work was defining an Interface, `IRow` and applying it to the 'Row' classes, `RowA` and `RowB`.

For the sake of future readers here are the classes which now work.

Two points

- I have changed the code a little from the previous example code within the properties/methods to make them more succinct and to resolve an unrelated defects;
- `RowA` and `RowB` are unrealistically similar, this is only to allow the issue to be illustrated simply and briefly, clearly in a real implementation they would be less similar.

```
class DisplayGrid<T> where T : IRow 
{
    public List<T> allRows;

    public DisplayGrid()
    {
        this.allRows = new List<T>();
    }

    public bool hasRowMsgs 
    {
        get
        {
            bool blnHasRowMsgs = false;
            foreach (T r in this.allRows)
            {
                if (!(r.isAValidRow))
                {
                    blnHasRowMsgs = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return blnHasRowMsgs;
        }
    }
    public bool isAValidTable
    {
        get {
            return (!(this.hasRowMsgs));
        }
    }
}
interface IRow
{
    bool isAValidRow { get; }
}
public class RowA : IRow 
{
    public List<string> rowMsgs;

    public bool isAValidRow {
        get {
            return this.rowMsgs.Count > 0 ? false : true;
        }
    }

    public RowA()
    {
        rowMsgs = new List<string>();
    }
}
public class RowB : IRow 
{
    public List<string> rowMsgs;

    public bool isAValidRow {
        get {
            return this.rowMsgs.Count > 0 ? false : true;
        }
    }

    public RowB()
    {
        rowMsgs = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this as an answer.

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to use C# rather than Java naming conventions for C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first line to

```
class DisplayGrid<T> where T : Row
```

then it should work.

Explanation: The method you are trying to use is a property of a Row; it is not a method of 'class' so it is not recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realise that my initial example wasn't sufficiently clear and this has caused some confusion. I've tried to improve the example so if you're willing to take another look I would appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I thought that the problem was more simple than it actually was. I'm glad you got an answer.